# how to delete all associated relational model record of a model from laravel?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.6, php-7.2

I am using **laravel 5.6**. i want to delete all child model as long as parent. that means if i delete parent then all child models record should delete self.

check this query.

```
$d= ParentModel::where('id',2)->with('child_1' ,'child_2','child_3')->first();
```

here i do not want to define loop and any thing else for delete all record of parent and child table. just want to delete parent and all its child table should also delete self.

I don't know. is this possible to delete all associated  model directly without mentioned.
like this way.

```
$d-> child_1->delete();
$d-> child_2->delete();
$d-> child_3->delete();
$d-> delete();
```

Comment: Why not setup a foreign key?

Comment: yes we can do. but it is little bit complex. will you send me any link for set up foreign key in laravel?

Comment: Are you using laravel migrations?

Comment: yes , but not mentioned foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You can add a foreign key to your child's table migration:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('parent_id');

$table->foreign('parent_id')
    ->references('id')->on('parent_table_name')
    ->onUpdate('cascade')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Now when you delete the parent, the child rows will be deleted automatically.

For more information about foreign keys: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Here is deletion code

```
$parentModel = ParentModel::find($id);  
$parentModel->child_1()->delete(); // return deleted record count
$parentModel->child_2()->delete(); // return deleted record count
$parentModel->child_3()->delete(); // return deleted record count
```